# How to Pick array values from BeanShell PostProcessor one by one

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

How to Pick array values from BeanShell PostProcessor one by one
I have code like below

```
//Here split those ',' separated values
// getting this values like List=1072,1073,1074, ......

String HID = vars.get("List"); String[] words = HID.split(","); 
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
{
  log.info(words[i]);
  if (i == 0) 
  {
      log.info("First value is: " + words[0]);
  }
}
vars.put("H_ID", words[0]);
```

I want to pick all values one by one. For that i used `vars.put("Hit_ID", words[i]);` But not work out.it is only work for `words[0]` or `words[2]` like that
But i want all values.
Can someone please help me in this how to pick all values one by one and substitute in next request.

Answer (score 0):

You're using only first item so your `HD_ID` will **always** contain **first** value, i.e. `1072`. If you need all the values you need to amend your code like:

```
String HID = vars.get("List"); String[] words = HID.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    log.info(words[i]);
    if (i == 0) {
        log.info("First value is: " + words[0]);
    }
    vars.put("H_ID_" + i, words[i]);
}
```

This way you will get the following variables:

```
H_ID_0=1072
H_ID_1=1073
H_ID_2=1074
```

A better option would be using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language instead as [since JMeter 3.1 users are strongly recommended to switch to Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for all scripting tasks. Groovy equivalent would be

```
vars.get('List').split(',').eachWithIndex { String number, int index ->
    vars.put("HD_ID_" + index, number)
}
```

Groovy is more "advanced" language, it supports all the modern Java features and provides some [syntax sugar](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of Java SDK. Moreover Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Comment: How Can i use "HD_ID_" value in next request.i tried like HD_ID_n but not work. could you please suggest me.

Comment: The correct syntax is `${H_ID_1}`, `${H_ID_2}`, etc

Comment: The correct syntax is ${H_ID_1}, ${H_ID_2}, here i want all values one by one like first iteration ${H_ID_1} and second iteration ${H_ID_2} ...like i want pick the values

Comment: Use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)  with "Input variable prefix" of `H_ID` like described in [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) article

Comment: Working. Thank you Dmitri T

Comment: This solution works in my scripts. I was spend to tried complete day for this function. After posted my issue here it was resolved with in 10 min of time my script working as i am expected.